# Generating unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of a set of integers

Tags: python, recursion, subset, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to generate the unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of a set S of integers.
As shown in [1], when S consists of n integers, we generate around 3<sup>n</sup>/2 pairs.
Now, I know how to generate all 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of S (i.e. the powerset of S), and for every subset (consisting of k integers) I could thus generate the kC2 (k choose 2) possible pairs.
But this is inefficient, because pairs will end up being generated more than once.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is some efficient (recursive) way to generate these pairs of subsets from S? I could not find any existing implementations and my own attempts using for example Python's itertools were not succesful so far.

[1] [Total number of unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of S (MathOverflow)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223425/total-number-of-unordered-pairs-of-disjoint-subsets-of-s/1223442)